# ionic-footer no visible en modo escritorio

Tags: angular, ionic

¿Es posible poner el footer al final del contenido en ionic?

Tengo la estructura como marca en la documentación

```
<ion-app>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</ion-app>
```

Dentro del `<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>` contiene un `<ion-content></ion-content>`

La idea es que la aplicación contenga un footer, pero no que tape el contenido de la web, como hace por defecto IONIC

Tengo una manera de solventarlo, pero debería meterlo en cada uno de los componentes y no creo que sea la solución correcta.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes probar esta estructura para evitar el overlap

```
    <ion-app>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>    
      <ion-title>Header</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>     
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content >
   <ion-router-outlet >
   </ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-footer>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo mismo que tengo. Pero tu has sacado el header y el footer fuera de los componentes.

Comment: .... solo debes cambiar  ion-header y ion-toolbar por tus componentes, el ion-router-outlet debe ir dentro de un ion- content.

Comment: Si si, por eso digo, que es exactamente lo mismo que tengo. Y no funciona.